# Android aar library obfuscation

Tags: java, android, jar, obfuscation, aar

I've got an .aar library that will get supplied to customers to be used in their applications. This library is basically an API with several web service calls to our own services.
By looking at the .class files of this .aar it is quite easy to get the server addresses and guess the GET parameters.

This is what I'd like to avoid. Is there any way to hide those addresses from people looking at the class files?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something similar. The only difference being the need to actually hide the code I use to do certain things.
In your case, hiding the code won't be of any use since anyone can actually monitor the traffic and see what requests are made(with what parameters).

Answer (score 0):

[Proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) has built-in support free in the Android build system but will not encrypt strings.

[Dexguard](https://www.saikoa.com/dexguard) is a paid tool that includes string encryption and other features.

For a full comparison see this chart: https://www.saikoa.com/comparison-proguard-and-dexguard